# Changing Scientific Format in HTML File to General or Text Format

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

When I run a query in PeopleSoft I have the option of opening it as a run to HTML file (which results in a .csv file) or as run to an Excel file.
The issue is that when it is opened in HTML certain numbers populated as 337E000159 (1st part is a product number "337E0" and the 2nd part is a project number "00159") get changed to scientific numbers such as 3.37E+161
The issue may be with the"7E0" part of the number. Excel may not like this for some reason.

Here is how they show up in the query:

Column A                        Column B

"42378                          3.37E+161 (as HTML)"

"000000000042378                337E000159 (as EXCEL)"

As you can see there is a two digit difference between 159 and 161.

When I try to change the scientific number to general or text it does not change. It remains the same. I've tried all the tricks to change it to text format but won't work.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Let me know if more information is needed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't perform any number conversions like that so Im going to guess that you are opening the CSV in Excel.

If this is what you are doing then you need to quote the text CSV fields (which is how you want this field to be interpreted).

Comment: Yes, I am opening it in .csv

Comment: This is where the number is showing as scientific which causes the number to change.  I don't know how to change it to text or number which will give me the same result as when I open the file with Excel.  I need to open this file as .csv and not .xls